# On transcendentals from sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say we have a sequence of integers $N_{k}$ where $k \in \Bbb N$. Can $\limsup_k \sqrt[k]{N_{k}}$ be transcendental?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a real $r>1$ let $N_k=\lfloor r^k \rfloor$, then $\sqrt[k]{N_{k}}$ tends to $r$.